# PHP-EWS while loop error Cannot redeclare class EwsSendEmail

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, php-ews

I am trying to pull out emails from a SQL database and then send an email to each of those emails using EWS via PHP.  But when I put the PHP-EWS code https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/ inside of a while loop it gives me the error *"Cannot redeclare class EwsSendEmail"*.

Here the layout of the code, it would look like I cannot have the class inside the while loop.  But not sure how else I can get all the data from the SQL table and send a unique email for each and I am not very familiar with the use of a class. The code works fine if I only pull one record from the SQL by adding TOP 1 after SELECT.  I do appreciate any help.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT FIELDNAME FROM TABLE";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false ) {
die (print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while ( $column = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
// Do some data processing here
require_once($ewspath.'EWSType/IncludetheEWSFilesHere.php');
class EwsSendEmail
{
    protected function sendEmail()
    {
        $server = 'myserver';
        $username = 'myuser';
        $password = 'mypass';
        $ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password);

        // Process the EWS Code Here

        $response = $ews->CreateItem($message);
        //var_dump($response);
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }
}
$page = new EwsSendEmail();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked around this issue by removing the class and function and just including the php code in the while loop. Maybe not the best practice solution but it works.